# Simple count function does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I thought making a  simple function where if you click on a button a number will show up inside of a paragraph. And if you continue to click on the button the number inside the paragraph tag will increase. However, I'm getting an error message saying that **getElementsByTagName** is not a function. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nz1fjf57/) is the code on jsfiddle, I know there is something simple that I'm doing wrong but I don't know what it is.

HTML

```
<div class="resist" id="ex1"><h2>Sleep</h2><p></p><button>Resist</button></div>

<div  class="resist" id="ex2"><h2>Eat</h2><p></p><button>Resist</button></div>
```

Javascript

```
var count = 0;
var resist = document.getElementsByClassName('resist') ;
for(var i = 0; i < resist.length; i++)
{    var a = resist[i];

    a.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(a){
       count +=1;
        a.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting `a` variable with event object passed into event handler. Change the name to `e` maybe, or remove it altogether as you are not using it anyway:

```
a.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e /* <--- this guy */) {
  count += 1;
  a.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;      
});
```

Another problem you are going to have is classical [closure-in-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) issue. One of the solutions would be to use Array.prototype.forEach instead of for loop:

```
var count = 0;
var resist = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('resist'));
// ES6: var resist = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('resist'));

resist.forEach(function(a) {
  a.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    count += 1;
    a.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;
  });
});
```

Comment: It somewhat works, but now another problem arises. Whenever I click on the two buttons the number only increments in the second .resist area.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the expected behaviour. Is it what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/nz1fjf57/2/ ? Or you want separate counters for each .resist?

Comment: I definitely wanted separate counters. Yours works better, but I wanted both of the paragraphs to start at 0. I guess I should just make another counter for each resist div?

Comment: Quick question, I don't know if you have time to answer this, but can you give me an explanation as to why you chose to use Array.prototype.slice.call instead of document.getElementsByClassName? I was wondering why you thought that was a better choice

Answer (score 0):

`vars` in Javascript are function scoped, so you must wrap your event listener binding in a [closure function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake) to ensure the variable you're trying to update is correctly set.

(*Note:* I've renamed `a` to `div` in the outer function and removed the arg from the inner click function).

```
var count = 0;
var resist = document.getElementsByClassName('resist') ;
var div;
for(var i = 0; i < resist.length; i++)
{   
    div = resist[i];
    (function(div){
        div.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
            count +=1;
            div.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;
        });
    })(div);
}
```